# How to pay out money to multiple paypal or venmo or checking accounts from a single business account inside an iOS app

Tags: ios, paypal, payment, venmo

In our app, we are trying to implement a payout feature. If the user correctly performs Action A, we want to be able to pay some incentive money to this user, assuming the user has already connected his account to PayPal or Venmo.

How can I implement this, do PayPal and/or Venmo SDKs/APIs make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Venmo does not allow you to send money from a business to customers. PayPal does, I believe. You should do this from a backing web service, rather than the app itself. To complete the payment from the app, you would need to embed your account information in the app itself, which would be a security disaster.

Comment: thanks Kevin, a backing web service as in a web application with a REST API??

Comment: REST wouldn't necessarily be a requirement, but it's what everybody is doing these days (and for good reason), so let's say yes. You want to initiate the payout from the backend so that you can keep the account details private and secure. You should always assume that whatever goes into the app can be read by everyone. For that reason, it's entirely possible that someone will reverse engineer the API you create in an attempt to generate more payout. You'll have to throttle the payout to prevent anyone from abusing the service and stealing your money.